# Access denied on Workflow.aspx after workflow manager 2013 configuration

Tags: workflow-manager

We are not being able to manually start the workflow after registering workflow manager to a sharepoint site. The message is "Access is denied"

What should we do ?

Answer (score 0):

You Should've a **contribute** right on the SharePoint *site*.

check this link will give you a good explanation also possible workaround:

http://steve.thelineberrys.com/unable-to-manually-start-workflows/

Comment: That is not the correct solution. It is not possible to provide contribute access to all the users of the organization.

Comment: @Raxak check this link will give you a good explanation http://steve.thelineberrys.com/unable-to-manually-start-workflows/